# dispatch is not a function - Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I m practicing an e-commerce app in react and redux. While working on it I have meet an error where the console is saying "dispatch is not a function". Although redux-thunk is working fine in other action creators. But in the following action, I m getting this error.

Here is the code from **product.jsx**

```
const Product = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Circle />
      <Image src={item.img} />
      <Info>
        <Icon>
// ----------Here is the Event handler -------------
           
          <ShoppingCartOutlined onClick={addToCart(item)}/>

// ------------------ end ----------------
        </Icon>
        <Icon>
          <SearchOutlined />
        </Icon>
        <Icon>
          <FavoriteBorderOutlined />
        </Icon>
      </Info>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Here is the code from the action creator **cart.js**

```
import { ADD_TO_CART } from "../constatns/actionConstants";


export const addToCart = item => dispatch =>{

    try {
        
        const cartItems = [];
        let alreadyInCart = false;
    
        cartItems.forEach(cartItem => {
            if(cartItem.id === item.id){
                alreadyInCart = true;
                cartItem.count++
            }
        })
        if(!alreadyInCart){
            cartItems.push({...item, count: 1})
        }
    
        dispatch({type: ADD_TO_CART, payload: cartItems})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }


}
```

And here is the **cart reducer**

```
import {ADD_TO_CART} from "../constatns/actionConstants";

const cart = (state = {cartItems: []}, action) => {

    if(action.type === ADD_TO_CART) {

        return {...state, cartItems: action.payload}
    }else {

        return state
    }
}
export default cart
```

Moreover Would one please also elaborate the difference between using `<Icon onClick={() => addToCart(item)} /> and <Icon onClick={addToCart(item)} />`. I somtimes get confused. And also when should I use both thses cases.

Highly looking forward,
Thanks :)

Comment: How do you import `dispatch` ?

Comment: Why is there a need to import the dispatch? It should be provided with the redux store if I m not wrong. Moreover, in other files, it's working fine without any import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a quick summary what should happen in your app.

1. you **dispatch** an action.
2. that action could be either an object, that goes straight to reducer.
3. or it can be a function definition, that goes to redux-thunk.
4. redux thunk gives it the **dispatch** function as argument, and calls it.

so, using Redux-thunk and using functions as actions (like `addToCart`), you also need to dispatch those actions, so,

```
          <ShoppingCartOutlined onClick={()=>dispatch(addToCart(item))}/>
```

dispatch could be defined in these two ways:

1.using useDispatch hook from react-redux package.

2.using mapDispatchToProps function.

onClick prop should be a function definition, whenever a click event happens, react calls that function.

**onClick={addToCart(item)}** ,

`addToCart(item)` returns this function definition:

```
    dispatch =>{

    try {
        
        const cartItems = [];
        let alreadyInCart = false;
    
        cartItems.forEach(cartItem => {
            if(cartItem.id === item.id){
                alreadyInCart = true;
                cartItem.count++
            }
        })
        if(!alreadyInCart){
            cartItems.push({...item, count: 1})
        }
    
        dispatch({type: ADD_TO_CART, payload: cartItems})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }


}
```

And this definition will be called by react, but it's wrong. because that definition should be received by redux-thunk.

**onClick={() => addToCart(item)}**

now the function definition called by react after click is `() => addToCart(item)`. still wrong due to the reasons i explained above.